# how to define path in app.route(' path ')

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Everyone, I am a beginner for the mongodb and nodejs. Can anyone suggest me how to and what to mention as a path in `app.route('/')`?

**Can anyone help me what to write in `app.route( '')`**

```
var express=require('express');
var app=express();


var MongoClient=require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url='mongodb://localhost/mydb';
var str="";
MongoClient.connect(url,{ useNewUrlParser: true },function(err,db){
    console.log("connected");
    db.close();
});

app.route('/').get(function(req,res){
    MongoClient.connect(url,function(err,db){
    var cursor=db.collection('collection').find();
cursor.each(function(err,item){
    if(item!=null){
        str=str+"&nbsp;&nbsp;Employee Id &nbsp;&nbsp; "+item.empid;
    }
});
res.send(str);
});
});

var server=app.listen(3000,function(){});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing **you should never create database connection inside API call**.  It'll create DB connection for every request. You can create get api using `app.get(path, callback)`.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();


var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost/mydb';
var str = "";
var db;
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, client) {
    db = client.db(dbName);
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    const collection = db.collection('collection');
    // Find some documents
    collection.find({}).toArray(function (err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            //Do something
        }
        // Do something
        return res.json(docs);
    });
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {});
```

Comment: Your Code is working great ! can u tell me how to find a particular key value   , I have tried collection.find({empid:1},{id:0}).toArray(function (err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            //Do something
        }
        // Do something
        return res.json(docs);
    });  one or more than one from a db and store it in a variable to present in a html file. But it not works

Comment: do you have data in collection?

Answer (score 0):

The path you need to use is related to your use-case. You can find more information about express routing here: https://expressjs.com/fr/guide/routing.html.

For example, if you were to create a social-network app, you could have the following paths:

- `/`
- `/dashboard`
- `/profile/1234`
- `/posts`
- ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create multiple request types (POST, GET, DELETE...) for the same url, you can use `app.route()`. Other than that you don't need to use `app.route()` function. You can simply use `app.get('/')` But you can still use it. In your code, you handle the GET requests coming to  http://localhost:3000/. If you write `app.post('/user/create')`, then it means you handle the POST requests coming to  http://localhost:3000/user/create

You should not connect to the database inside a route. Instead, connect to Mongodb server once and use the same connection for each of your requests.